# Swift parameterized function not allowing to use in the code objective c

Tags: objective-c, swift

I'm using the swift functions inside objective C file. I can use most of the functions that are without any parameter that is- `Print()` kind of function, but the problem arises for any kind of parameter function except for some.

Xcode also doesn't show autocompletion for parameterized function.

Function for which the compiler doesn't show error, working fine and shows autocompletion:

```
1.
public func N500() -> Dictionary<String, String>? {
        return [
            KEY_ERROR_ID: ID_N500,
            KEY_LEVEL: LEVEL_ERROR
        ]
    }
2.
public func CFG(_ code: Int) -> Dictionary<String, Any>? {
        let codeStr = "\(ID_CFG)\(code)"
        return [
            KEY_ERROR_ID: codeStr,
            KEY_LEVEL: LEVEL_ERROR,
            KEY_MESSAGE: "Configuration call error"
        ]
    }
```

Function for which the compiler shows error and also not show autocompletion:

```
1.
public func VSA503(_ reason: NSString?) -> Dictionary<String, String?>? {
        return [
            KEY_ERROR_ID: ID_VSA503,
            KEY_LEVEL: LEVEL_WARNING,
            KEY_MESSAGE: reason
        ]
    }
2.
public func Z100(_ resource: String?,  message: String?) -> Dictionary<String, String?>? {
        return [
            KEY_ERROR_ID: ID_Z100,
            KEY_LEVEL: LEVEL_ERROR,
            KEY_RESOURCE: resource,
            KEY_MESSAGE: message
        ]
    }
3.
public func REG(_ code: Int) -> Dictionary<String, Any>? {
        let codeStr = "\(ID_REG)\(code)"
        return [
            KEY_ERROR_ID: codeStr,
            KEY_LEVEL: LEVEL_ERROR,
            KEY_MESSAGE: "Registration code call error"
        ]
    }
```

The above codes are some kinds which shows error, there are more codes but they are kinda same.

I'm calling that swift function in objective C code as:

```
LegacyStatus *legacyStatus = [[LegacyStatus alloc]init];
[context.accessEnabler dispatchStatus:[legacyStatus CFG:statusCode.intValue]];
```

this code is working, added `@class swift-file` annotation in `.m` file in which I'm using this function.

I found one StackOverflow question like this but not same, but it didn't help.

Edit: When I try to use without that autocompletion feature with the code below:

```
LegacyStatus *legacyStatus = [[LegacyStatus alloc]init];
[context.accessEnabler dispatchStatus:[legacyStatus REG:statusCode.intValue]];
```

it shows `expected ]`. when I try to build. I don't think that it's a syntax error because with the same syntax I'm able to use other function.

Comment: Please go to the Generated Bridge Header file, and look for the method declarations in Objective-C, you should see them then. And "show errors"? What errors? When? Where? I tested with `CFG:` and didn't get any issue.

Comment: Edited the question. Please let me know if any other info is needed.

Comment: `[legacyStatus REG.intValue]` means that `legacyStatys` have a property named `REG` which has a `intValue` method (I'd tend to say that `REG` is then a `NSNumber`). I'd better be: `[legacyStatus REG:REG.intValue]`? Or something like that, it's unclear what's the param, or `REG.intValue` is `statusCode.intValue`, that's unclear.

Comment: So sorry, It's basically same as the above working code of CFG. Fixed it

Comment: "expected ]"? Maybe before then, it's missing a "]".

Comment: no actually, as I mentioned in the question. The both are same but the latter gives error.

Comment: I mean. Comment the two lines. Do you still have a compiler error? If yes, then the error might be somewhere else. Or write: NSDictionary *reg = [legacyStatus REG:statusCode.intValue]; [context.accessEnabler dispatchStatus:reg]`, and tell us which line is causing the error?

Comment: I think I got the fix. before parameter functions we have to use 
`@objc(functionname:) functionname{...}`
This fixed the issue.